# AttributeError: while using monkeypatch of pytest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

`src/mainDir/mainFile.py`

contents of mainFile.py

```
import src.tempDir.tempFile as temp

data = 'someData'
def foo(self):
    ans = temp.boo(data)
    return ans
```

`src/tempDir/tempFile.py`

```
def boo(data):

   ans = data
   return ans
```

Now I want to test `foo()` from `src/tests/test_mainFile.py` and I want to mock `temp.boo(data)` method in `foo()` method

```
 import src.mainDir.mainFile as mainFunc

  testData = 'testData'
  def test_foo(monkeypatch):
     monkeypatch.setattr('src.tempDir.tempFile', 'boo', testData)
     ans = mainFunc.foo()
     assert ans == testData
```

but I get error

> AttributeError: 'src.tempDir.tempFile' has no attribute 'boo'

I expect ans = testData.

I would like to know if I am correctly mocking my tempDir.boo() method or I should use pytest's mocker instead of monkeypatch.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You're telling monkeypatch to patch the attribute `boo` of the string object you pass in.

You'll either need to pass in a module like `monkeypatch.setattr(tempFile, 'boo', testData)`, or pass the attribute as a string too (using the two-argument form), like `monkeypatch.setattr('src.tempDir.tempFile.boo', testData)`.

Comment: FYI, the two-argument form for `setattr` is no longer supported. See docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html

Comment: @KyleKing That's not correct - it's just missing from the docs (it's in the reference docs). See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/8297

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I updated my answer. I tried the two argument form to test before commenting, but I must not have read the error message carefully

Answer (score 3):

My use case was was slightly different but should still apply. I wanted to patch the value of `sys.frozen` which is set when running an application bundled by something like Pyinstaller. Otherwise, the attribute does not exist. Looking through the pytest docs, the `raising` kwarg controls wether or not AttributeError is raised when the attribute does not already exist. ([docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch.setattr))

## Usage Example

```py
import sys

def test_frozen_func(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(sys, 'frozen', True, raising=False)
    # can use ('fq_import_path.sys.frozen', ...)
    # if what you are trying to patch is imported in another file
    assert sys.frozen
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: mocking function calls can be done with `monkeypatch.setattr('package.main.slow_fun', lambda: False)` (see answer and comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666743/3219667) and updated snippet below

---

I don't think this can be done with pytest's monkeypatch, but you can use the `pytest-mock` package. Docs: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock

Quick example with the two files below:

```py
# package/main.py
def slow_fun():
    return True

def main_fun():
    if slow_fun():
        raise RuntimeError('Slow func returned True')
```

```py
# tests/test_main.py
from package.main import main_fun

# Make sure to install pytest-mock so that the mocker argument is available
def test_main_fun(mocker):
    mocker.patch('package.main.slow_fun', lambda: False)
    main_fun()

# UPDATE: Alternative with monkeypatch
def test_main_fun_monkeypatch(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('package.main.slow_fun', lambda: False)
    main_fun()
```

Note: this also works if the functions are in different files